# MySQL with Asp.net encoding issue

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have a legacy MySQL database encoded in Latin-1, And it has Arabic text..

When retrieving data to a php page its shown correctly.. but it shows weird chars like 'ÇáÅÚáÇä' when data viewed in an asp.net page.. I've tried many fixes but none solved my problem.. 
This caused me headache in the past few days and i would appreciate it a lot of anyone can give me a working fix for this.. thanks in advance.

Comment: If it has Arabic text, that *can't* be encoded in ISO-Latin-1, as that doesn't include Arabic characters. Goodness knows what's actually being stored, but it's not ISO-Latin-1...

Comment: Current Collation is latin1_general_ci .. and Arabic text is stored in it,, when table contents are view using the online database explorer it shows the same weird chars,, but it show the normal chars when viewed in any simple php page.